# Sort search results in woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I need to sort the search results of my store in the following way: first display the products that are available in inventory and then those that are out of stock.

I managed to do it for the products page (shop) with the following snippet:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args', 'first_sort_by_stock_amount', 9999 );
 
function first_sort_by_stock_amount( $args ) {
   $args['orderby'] = 'meta_value';
   $args['meta_key'] = '_stock_status';
   return $args;
}
```

But applying the same snippet to wc_product_meta_lookup doesn't work.

I've been told to try the pre_get_post hook but no results so far.

Could you help me?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to my problem by implementing this snippet:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_query', 'sort_by_stock_status_and_date', 999 );
function sort_by_stock_status_and_date( $query ) {
    if ( is_admin() ) return;

    $query->set( 'meta_key', '_stock_status' );
    $query->set( 'orderby', array( 'meta_value' => 'ASC', 'date' => 'DESC' )  );
}
```

In addition to filtering the products by stock (first the available ones and then the out of stock) it works with all the queries so I stopped using the snippet that it showed in my question.